# JUnit custom annotation

Tags: java, junit, annotations

I wanted to create a custom JUnit annotation, something similar to expected tag in @Test, but I want to also check the annotation message.

Any hints how to do that, or maybe there is something ready?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JUnit 4.9 tightened up the library's use of "rules" for tests, which I think might work as well as a custom annotation. Take a look at [TestRule](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TestRule.html) as a starting point. You can implement a rule based on that interface, and then use either the @ClassRule or (method-level) @Rule annotations to put them into play in your tests.

A good concrete example is [ExpectedException](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html), which lets you specify exceptions like the expected parameter for @Test does (and then some).

Answer (score 6):

To make JUnit4 pickup your custom annotations, you need to write your own custom Runner implementation, and then supply that to the RunWith-annotation on the Test class.

You can start out by having a look at the BlockJUnit4ClassRunner, which is the default implementation runner for JUnit 4 (if memory serves me well).

Assuming you would want to pick up a custom annotation named @MyTest with a custom runner MyRunner, your test class would look something like:

```
@RunWith(MyRunner.class)
class Tests {
   ...
   @MyTest
   public void assumeBehaviour() {
      ...
   }
}
```

The answer by "Reid Mac" does a fairly good job at decribing how a custom annotation is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom [TestRule](http://junit-team.github.com/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/TestRule.html) as mentioned in first answer or you can use/extend [TestWatcher](http://junit-team.github.com/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html) that already have method for processing start/finish of test.
There is a method `apply(Statement base, Description description)` where description is actually a wrapper around your test method. [Description](http://junit-team.github.com/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/runner/Description.html) has a great method [getAnnotation(annotationClass)](http://junit-team.github.com/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/runner/Description.html#getAnnotation%28java.lang.Class%29) which will let you do what you want by specifying a custom annotation you want to process